# Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 465,

Tags: php, mysql

I have config the wamp server and have made changes to relevant files as well but i am getting above error again and again so please help me to get over it ..... because it is too hectic......

This is my mail() function code

```
 <?php
   if(mail('vipinkumarsn4@gmail.com','Hello', 'hello', 'noreply@gmail.com'))
        echo "Email sent";
    else
        echo "Email sending failed";
    ?>
```

This is my sendmail.ini file

```
         [sendmail]
     smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

        ; smtp port (normally 25)

        smtp_port=465

        ; SMTPS (SSL) support
        ;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
        ;   ssl  = alway use SSL
        ;   tls  = always use TLS
        ;   none = never try to use SSL

        smtp_ssl=ssl
```

php.ini file

```
[mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    SMTP = localhost
    smtp_port = 465

    ; For Win32 only.
    sendmail_from = vipin.cybomate@gmail.com
```

Comment: Have you an smtpserver on localhost?

Comment: @Jens yes i do have...... i have installed the sendmail

Comment: Have you confirmed anything else connect to it? At the very least, telnet to localhost port 465.

Comment: Erm, what server are you actually trying to connect to? Your `php.ini` says `localhost` while `sendmail.ini` says `smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: @Deanna i am trying to connect with wamp server

Comment: @user1751437 on localhost? How about making the settings files match and testing that you can connect with anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You must activate SSL chanel. use 'auto' protocol

```
    ; SMTPS (SSL) support
    ;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
    ;   ssl  = alway use SSL
    ;   tls  = always use TLS
    ;   none = never try to use SSL

    smtp_sll = auto;  // otherwise try to use TLS
```

Comment: Did you try "tls" too? I have concerns about it is not about gmail setup. Did you try or ever make it work with a regular (port:25 or 26) email account?